# Animate card widget on button click Tinder like swipe

Tags: flutter, animation, onclick, swipe

Hello all I am building Tinder like swipe in Flutter. So far so good I have made the stack of cards together with the gesture detector when the user swipes left/right. However my issue come when I try to animate on click of a button. Under the stack of cards there are 2 buttons which you can like or dislike on button click. I would like to get an advice how I can approach the animation when the user clicks on either button. Below is my code for displaying the stack. Best wishes

Comment: Is the animation part of a page transition or do you stay on the same screen?

Comment: hello Jacob, I would like to apply a animation like as if the user has swiped on the card but on a button click so after he clicks on a button, animation is not part of page transition and the user should stay on the same screen. Regards

Answer (score 0):

There are several options to animate the card off screen. Since you're already using a Stack, [AnimatedPosition](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedPositioned-class.html) is probably the best option.

You could also use `Transform.translate` to set the `transform` property of an [AnimatedContainer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedContainer-class.html). Or, if you want more control over the animation you could use a [SlideTransition](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SlideTransition-class.html).

For a good overview of how to decide which animations you need, see this video from two days ago: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GXIJJkq_H8g

There's also https://pub.dev/packages/animations for more pre-packed options.